# js function inside function and wait for return value

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // Global function (will be include in any HTML file)
    function m3_result(size_1, size_2, size_3){
        $.get('http://www.google.com', function(data){
            return data;
        });
    }   

    // Another function
    function calculate(){
        var size_1 = parseFloat($('#add_document_form #size_1').val());
        var size_2 = parseFloat($('#add_document_form #size_2').val());
        var size_3 = parseFloat($('#add_document_form #size_3').val());          
        var ax = m3_result(size_1, size_2, size_3);

        alert(ax); // Here ax return: UNDEFINED  
    }

    // Run
    calculate();
});
```

Results are "undefined", but I would like that calculate() will wait for m3_result() to execute. I see that here problem is coming when I added $.get(), but its needed...

I have searching for callback() like functions, but none fit to my needs, or I just didnt put that right.
Any help will be highly appreciated, thanks.

---

GET url will be localy and element IDs are also ok.

Comment: Also you probably will experience a SOP violation if you really are `GET`ting `www.google.com`

Comment: Please show us how you tried to use a callback function - it is indeed the solution

Comment: NB: there's no need to reference `#add_document_form` in your selectors.  IDs have to be unique, so `#size_1` could only ever refer to one element, so its parent is irrelevant.

Comment: GET url at my side will be used local not http://

Comment: Also element IDs are ok

Comment: @LaurisKuznecovs sure, the element IDs will work - they're just unnecessarily specific, and potentially slower than they would be if you just said `#size_1`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't return a result from an asynchronous function, instead you can return a *promise* to supply that value later, which as it happens is the `jqXHR` object returned by `$.get`:

```
function m3_result() {
     return $.get(...)
}
```

and do the same in calculate:

```
function calculate() {
    ...
    return m3_result(...); 
}
```

and then wait for the result, which will be passed as a parameter to the callback registered with the `.done` function:

```
calculate().done(function(result) {
    alert(result);
});
```

Comment: Returning the promise is really nice, even if the q is a duplicate I like this technique and used it before (---also, it's not mentioned in the dupe---).

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum  It _is_ mentioned in the dupe, but it's hidden away amongst many other possible solutions.  I always use this method, though.  In any event, I think it's often useful to give the OP a concrete example of how to use the technique for _their_ use case.

Comment: Cool, never seen this before but looks promising, boom-boom

Comment: Cool, this way it worked like a charm :)

Comment: But still one problem:

Comment: @LaurisKuznecovs and what's that problem?

Comment: But still one problem:

calculate().done(function(result) {
    alert(result); // return expected
    alert( $(document).html(); ); // return undefined
});

Comment: sounds like you're running that code before the DOM has been loaded.